# How to create a post implementation without response needed?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, post

I have to create a post implementation in android and NO RESPONSE IS EXPECTED. I have 2 parameters, but I don't wait response. How can I do this?

Comment: you have to wait for a sort of response so that you will know if the message was sent or not.

Comment: i know. but this is the api is implemented. I tried httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(json_params));
    
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost); and i get as response org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@420d3e48